# glTexImage2D much slower on Android 4.2.2 than 4.2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-4.2-jelly-bean, glteximage2d

We recently upgraded our Android devices from 4.2.0 to 4.2.2 only to realize that everything is now stuttering madly.

On Android 4.2.0 or lower, this call required roughly ***15 ms***.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width, height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer.position(position));
```

On Android 4.2.2, the same call requires between ***100 - 195 ms***. What on earth has changed that would cause this? We are multiple developers testing across multiple devices and are all getting this. I can't see anything in the change logs that would affect this. I have no idea how to move forwards from here.

As a note, the buffer in the above call is a ByteBuffer returned from MediaCodec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bug according to the bug database

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53135&q=nexus%2010&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Good to see we are no longer the only ones having this issue. Question now is when it will be fixed.